# apache url rewrite QUERY_STRING

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have some page, i want to modify from `localhost/wordpress/site/news?title=apple&num=1`

to `localhost/wordpress/site/news/apple/1/`

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /wordpress
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=(.*)&num=([0-9]+)$
  RewriteRule ^/wordpress/site/news$ /wordpress/site/news/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
  </IfModule>
  # END WordPress
```

In order to make a difference from other page, the better way may be use `site/news` instead of `news`. And may be need a final `/` for `localhost/wordpress/site/news/apple/1/`, because all these query page have some jquery slider plungin, witch relay on `fragment #` for `left` `right` control, also write in url rules. (`localhost/wordpress/site/news/apple/1/#2`)

I am sure `localhost/wordpress/site/news?title=apple&num=1` can work, but `localhost/wordpress/site/news/apple/1/` will jump into `localhost/wordpress/site/` How to do url rewrite in a right way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the wordpress .htaccess, and declare the permalink stucture using dasboard->settings->permalinks

I could write the routes for you, but wordpress can do it better

Comment: I have already setting `permalinks` with custom Structure with `/page/%post_name%`, they work well. now I only change one link's rule. thanks.